# web app running fine in jetty, but shows a 404 error in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jetty, war

I have a web application that deploys as a war file. I have been running in on jetty without any errors. The problem is when i try to deploy the same war file in tomcat. It deploys fine but when i try to access the application, it shows a 404 error.

What could possibly be causing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have very little useful information in this question.  Include whatever information you can.  What version of jetty or tomcat? how did you deploy? what did you do to test? what is the configuration within your webapp? what have you done to troubleshoot this? We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Share your research.

Answer (score 0):

Check your file structure and make sure it's referencing correctly. Try porting or pulling your app over to codenvy.com and then sharing a link to it. If it's in Git, you can just clone it into the codenvy IDE.